# Kinect's HandPointer and WPF Combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox, kinect

Im working on creating my own controlers with WPF. 
Everything goes fine until i meet popups object, which i cannot get because they are "drawn" on the top layer. When Button is clicked, the popup with list appears. Using mouse everything works fine. This one is controler made using popup and button, but simply combobox works the same. I attach picture to show how it looks.

 Is it possible to access that list somehow? 
[image: Hiding hand]

EDIT

```
    <Grid>
            <controls:KinectSensorChooserUI HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="sensorChooserUi" />
            <controls:KinectRegion Name="kinectRegion">
                <Grid x:Name="kinectRegionGrid" Margin="10,20,10,20">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Width="200"></ComboBox>
...
```

Comment: Better place some XAML code in your description aswell.

Comment: As you wish. Sorry for late answer, but i forgot about this question.

Comment: So what was the solution to this?  Did you have to create another control that acted like a popup control?

Comment: Unfortunatelly i give up on using Combobox and i've created something with ListBox and Button.